# I'm curious about last argument of Trace proof in Evans 275p.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence, trace

In Evans p274~275 Trace Theorem, I understood most details of proof, 
but I don't know ,in last paragraph of proof, **why u_m converge *uniformly* to u on the closure of U.** why uniformly? closure?

Comment: I don't have the book - and others may not. Can you write the result in question?

Comment: I don't think I have the same version, but it looks like the proof references the result in $\S 5.3.3$ Theorem 3. It builds $u_m$ to be a finite sum of mollified functions, which converge uniformly to continuous functions on compact sets. This is proven in Appendix C Theorem 6.